# download base_64 string as png in browser

Tags: php, javascript, png, base64

I edit a png image put some text on it and display is as

```
<?php    
ob_start();
imagepng($img, NULL);
$rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();
imagedestroy($img);
echo "<img id='ca_image' src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($rawImageBytes)     . "' />";

?>
<a href="#" onclick="return download();">Download</a>
<script>
function download(){
var img =document.getElementById("ca_image").src;
var url = img.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
location.href = url;
</script>
```

as i change the content type of file,browser automatically pop up window to download but downloaded file type is PART . i want to download base_64 as png file.
is this possible by this approach?
is this the right approach to save file as png?
if not Please suggest the right way to solve my problem.

Comment: Why don't you simply return the image without base64 encoding? You can set a PHP file wich returns an image as an image source.

Comment: i solve it as <input name="string" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base64_encode($rawImageBytes) ?>"/>       and in php---------$base64strImg=$_REQUEST['string'];
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.png"');----can itcreate some problem? as  have not check the string.
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        echo base64_decode($base64strImg);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i solve it as

```
 <input name="string" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base64_encode($rawImageBytes) ?>"/>
```

and in php

```
$base64strImg=$_REQUEST['string']; 
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.png"');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download'); 
echo base64_decode($base64strImg);
```

can it create some problem? as have not check the string.

Comment: image string is being send by form as hidden value and second snippets is for download image.

Comment: So you implemented just what I suggested and then accept that as your own answer... (y)